# angularjs ---- In the following code, I can not get the value of avatarPath

Tags: angularjs

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNJFb.png)

```
angular.module('Kinder.pages.member')
    .controller('MemberInfoCtrl', MemberInfoCtrl);

function MemberInfoCtrl($scope,MemberModel,Constants,fileReader,$filter,AppUtils,$http,toastr,API) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.member = {};
    vm.member.memberType = "1";
    vm.member.memberSex = "1";
    vm.member.avatarPath = "";

    $scope.getFile = function () {
        fileReader.readAsDataUrl($scope.file, $scope);
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files[0];
        if(!AppUtils.isUndefinedOrNull(fileInput)){
            var formData=new FormData();
            formData.append("picUrl",fileInput);
            $http({
                ........
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.stat == 'success'){
                    //vm will have avatarPath  value in there
                    console.log(vm);
                    vm.member.avatarPath = data.path;
                    //vm will have avatarPath  value in there
                    console.log(vm);
                }
            }).error(function(data, status) {
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        //vm had loss avatarPath ...
        console.log(vm.member);

    };

}
```

I do the function is to upload pictures before the preview, upload to the server to return to the path, assigned to vm。

But I can not get the avatarPath value outside the $ scope.getFile method。

I suspect that the problem of the scope of the problem, but I can not find a solution, I am the angular novice。

So who can tell me what this is for the reason。

I used google translation to describe the above questions，
I do not know if you understand me。。。

Anyway, thank you for taking the time to browse this question！

Comment: you have to do vm.member.avatarPath = ""; in success

Comment: @JayantPatil    thanks for you answer, you mean is put the "vm.member.avatarPath = '' " in http success method ?but  i had try it befor, it is cant get value aslo.......

Comment: try to print in data in console first then set to one scope variable then assign it to vm.members =  data;

Comment: @JayantPatil  i had upload a about  console log info picture in my question... i try it before ..

Comment: so do in html as <ng-cntroller='ctrl as vm'> {{vm.members}}

Answer (score 0):

i fix it!

thanks for @JayantPatil reminders！

i am declaring controller in the route

```
.state('member.info', {
            url: '/info/{memberId:string}',
            params: {
                memberId: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/member/info/member-info.html',
            controller: 'MemberInfoCtrl as vm'
        });
```

and in the html , i use the ng-controller

```
<div class="userpic" ng-controller="MemberInfoCtrl as vm">
   <input type="file" ng-show="false" id="uploadFile" ng-file-select/>
</div>
```

cause  i duplicate declarations  the controller , maybe the Scopes is Different，

that is all